# Is it possible to build pytorch to dlopen from a separate libtorch installation?

Tags: pytorch, setup.py, libtorch

I'd like to reuse my Linux libtorch installation in Pytorch as well. The benefits would be:

- reducing unpacked Python package size by ~600MB of shared objects
- certainty that I'm using the same backend implementation in both Python and other frontends

Is this possible? Scanning [the Pytorch code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/b0087b4cf7a523921050eeb223eaf8bc27f185f9/torch/__init__.py#L172), I don't see an obvious way (it seems to load via `CDLL` from a fixed path relative to `__init__.py`), but I'm not certain.

Extra context: It wasn't too hard to make a custom Pytorch build that used system CUDA/CUDNN libraries, so I'm somewhat encouraged and hope this is possible for libtorch as well.